# Mongoose Model.estimatedDocumentCount() TypeError

Tags: mongoose, count

I keep receiving the following error when trying to use estimatedDocumentCount function:
"TypeError: URLModel.estimatedDocumentCount is not a function"

Here is my code:

```
var mongo = require('mongodb'); //version: "^2.2.5"
var mongoose = require('mongoose'); //version "^4.5.7"

mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, function(err, db) {
 if (err) {console.log(err);}
});

var URLSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  original_url: {type: String, required: true, unique: true},
  short_url: {type: Number, required: true, unique: true}
});
var URLModel = mongoose.model('URLModel', URLSchema);
```

After creating new instances of URLModel and saving them in the database I would like to perform the following operation that causes the error:

```
var docCount = URLModel.estimatedDocumentCount();
```

I very much appreciate any help!
You can find the link to the full project here:
https://glitch.com/edit/#!/stormy-bagel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `mongoose 4.5.7` which doesn't have this function implemented but `estimatedDocumentCount` function was added in `mongoose 5.2.2`.

Check out this issue: [Link](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/6697)

Comment: Thank you very much! I highly appreciate your response!